# Basic CMake C++ project structure

Tags: c++, cmake

I started working on a C++ project using Google Test framework for unit testing and header-only [CImg](https://github.com/dtschump/CImg) library for internal operations. I want to use CMake build system to compile it.

```
$ tree
.
├── build
├── cmake
│   └── includes.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── soccl
│       └── soccl.hpp
└── src
    ├── soccl
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── soccl.cpp
    └── tests
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        ├── main.cpp
        └── soccl.cpp

7 directories, 8 files
```

Source:

```
# .gitignore
*.o
*.so

build
```

---

```
# CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)
project(SoftwareOccluder VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 -Os -Wall -pedantic")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-s ${CIMG_FLAGS}")

set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/external)

include_directories(include)
include(cmake/includes.cmake)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src/soccl)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src/tests)
```

---

```
# cmake/includes.cmake
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    cimg
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/dtschump/CImg.git
    SOURCE_DIR "cimg"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cimg)

SET(CIMG_FLAGS "-lm -lpthread")
```

---

```
/* include/soccl/soccl.hpp */
#ifndef SOCCL_HPP
#define SOCCL_HPP

#define cimg_display 0
#include <CImg.h>

namespace soccl {

struct RGB {
    int r, g, b;
};

class Soccl {
public:
    Soccl();

    RGB get_pixel(int x, int y);
    void set_pixel(int x, int y, RGB rgb);
private:
    cimg_library::CImg<unsigned char> img_;
};

} // namespace soccl

#endif
```

---

```
# src/soccl/CMakeLists.txt
file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_library(soccl SHARED ${SOURCES})
install(TARGETS soccl DESTINATION /usr/lib)
```

---

```
/* src/soccl/soccl.cpp */
#include "soccl/soccl.hpp"

namespace soccl {

Soccl::Soccl() : img_(320, 240, 1, 3) {
    img_.fill(0);
}

RGB Soccl::get_pixel(int x, int y) {
    RGB rgb;
    rgb.r = static_cast<int>(img_(x, y, 0, 0));
    rgb.g = static_cast<int>(img_(x, y, 0, 1));
    rgb.b = static_cast<int>(img_(x, y, 0, 2));
    return rgb; 
}

void Soccl::set_pixel(int x, int y, RGB rgb) {
    img_(x, y, 0, 0) = rgb.r;
    img_(x, y, 0, 1) = rgb.g;
    img_(x, y, 0, 2) = rgb.b;
}

} // namespace soccl
```

---

```
# src/tests/CMakeLists.txt
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    googletest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}
)
include_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION}/lib)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
file(GLOB TESTS "*.cpp")
add_executable(tests ${TESTS})
target_link_libraries(tests soccl gtest gmock gtest_main pthread)
```

---

```
/* src/tests/main.cpp */
#include "gmock/gmock.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    testing::InitGoogleMock(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

---

```
/* src/tests/soccl.cpp */
#include "soccl/soccl.hpp"

#include "gmock/gmock.h"

class SocclTest: public testing::Test {
public:
    soccl::Soccl soccl;
};

TEST_F(SocclTest, TestPixelGetter) {
    soccl::RGB rgb = soccl.get_pixel(10, 20);
    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.r, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.g, 0);
    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.b, 0);
}

TEST_F(SocclTest, TestPixelSetter) {
    soccl::RGB rgb{12, 21, 44};
    soccl.set_pixel(43, 23, rgb);

    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.r, 12);
    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.g, 21);
    ASSERT_EQ(rgb.b, 44);
}
```

Compilation:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

Running tests (compiled as a binary file in build dir):

```
$ ./tests 
[==========] Running 2 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 2 tests from SocclTest
[ RUN      ] SocclTest.TestPixelGetter
[       OK ] SocclTest.TestPixelGetter (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] SocclTest.TestPixelSetter
[       OK ] SocclTest.TestPixelSetter (0 ms)
[----------] 2 tests from SocclTest (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 2 tests from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 2 tests.
```

Comment: How is it working out for you so far, running as intended? Any trouble you encounter you'd want to improve?

Comment: Everything seems to work as intended. I'm mostly interested if I follow CMake best practices correctly, since I don't have much experience with it and presented C++ code is rather simple and straightforward.

Comment: You've gotta ask yourself one question: "Why would I use CMake on the first place?". With C/C++ pluralism there are numerous fancy ways of organizing and building projects. And CMake is rather sophisticated tool that can deal with many of such ways or even be extended to deal with even more fancier scenarios. But the thing is that with CMake overall code organization and project building complexity only gets higher. Actually I would even say that with CMake it instantly jumps on epic height. While all sorts of best practices suggest to keep things simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have asked for CMake best practices let me concentrate on that part. Here are my recommendations:

- Keep it cross-platform. Avoid compiler/platform specific settings.
- Reorder your project to use one sub-folder with one `CMakeLists.txt` for each target.
- Don't use `ExternalProject_Add()` if your project is on Git. Use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) instead.
- For external projects that don't come with CMake support use ["Imported Targets"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets).
- Don't use `file(GLOB ...)` to collect source files. CMake won't find newly added sources automatically otherwise.
- Add header files also to your target's source file list. It will otherwise not show up in generated IDE projects.
- Use [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) command to specify a C++ feature or a standard your project needs.
- Don't specify full paths as [`install(... DESTINATION ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) to allow the user of your library to specify another [`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html).
- Allow the user to specify his/her own [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html). Don't put it in your `CMakeList.txt` file.

I've uploaded my modified version to: https://github.com/FloriansGit/SoftwareOccluder

*Note*: Since the Git repository has submodules you need to add `--recursive` to your clone command like:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/FloriansGit/SoftwareOccluder.git
```

---

**.gitmodules**

```
[submodule "CImg"]
    path = CImg
    url = https://github.com/dtschump/CImg
[submodule "googletest"]
    path = googletest
    url = https://github.com/google/googletest
```

---

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(SoftwareOccluder VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

add_library(CImg INTERFACE IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_property(
    TARGET CImg 
    APPEND 
    PROPERTY
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CImg"
)

# Prevent overriding the parent project's compiler/linker
# settings on Windows
set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory("googletest")

add_subdirectory("soccl")
```

---

**soccl/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(
    SOURCES 
        "src/soccl.cpp"
        "include/soccl.hpp"
)

add_library(soccl ${SOURCES})
target_include_directories(soccl PUBLIC "include")
target_compile_features(soccl PUBLIC "cxx_std_14")
target_link_libraries(soccl CImg)

install(
    TARGETS soccl 
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
)

add_subdirectory("test")
```

---

**soccl/test/CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(
    TESTS 
        "src/main.cpp"
        "src/soccl_test.cpp"
)
add_executable(tests ${TESTS})
target_link_libraries(tests soccl gtest gmock)
```

---

#### References

- [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not being used in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt)
- [cmake add_library, followed by install library destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278381/cmake-add-library-followed-by-install-library-destination)
- [Why is cmake file GLOB evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil)
- [How to activate C++ 11 in CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851247/how-to-activate-c-11-in-cmake)
- [How to properly add include directories with CMake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake)
- [GitHub: Working with submodules](https://github.com/blog/2104-working-with-submodules)

Comment: I've got two errors on `cmake ..`: `The source directory /home/testuser/SoftwareOccluder/googletest does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.` and `target_compile_features specified unknown feature "cxx_std_14" for target "soccl".`

Comment: @Nykakin Since the Git repository has submodules you need to add `--recursive` to your clone command. Sorry forgot to mention this. That will fix the empty `googletest` directory. I've updated my answer accordingly. For the "unknown feature `cxx_std_14`" which compiler do you use? You can check what CMake does see as valid/supported features for your compiler with something like `message("CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES = ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILE_FEATURES}")`.